# Invariance of noneuclidean laplacian

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis, laplacian

In a book I'm reading it says: Putting $f(x,y)=F(u,v)$ with $\gamma(x+yi)=u+iv$ and using Cauchy-Riemann equation for $\gamma(z)$, we have

$$\Delta f(x,y) \overset{(*)}=-y^2(u_x^2+v_x^2)(F_{uu}+F_{vv})\overset{(**)}=-y^2|\frac{d}{dz}\gamma(z)|^2 (F_{uu}+F_{vv})=-v^2(F_{uu}+F_{vv}),$$

which amounts to $\Delta \cdot \gamma = \gamma \cdot \Delta$, i.e., the invariance of $\Delta$. Here $$\Delta = -y^2\left(\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)^2\right)$$
is the noneuclidean laplacian. And $\gamma$ is an element of modular group $\Gamma$ (I think).

I can't really see why we have the equalities (*) and (**). And why does this tell us the invariance (can't see that either)?

Comment: What connection is there between $f$ and $\gamma$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I dont think its mentioned in the book. $\gamma$ is just a element on modular group $\Gamma$.

Comment: By the way, which book?

Comment: @pre-kidney Spectral theory of Riemann zeta-function by Motohashi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equality $(*)$ is simply the chain rule applied to $f=F\circ \gamma$. Equation $(**)$ comes from
$$
\left|\frac{d\gamma}{dz}\right|^2=\frac{d\gamma}{dz}\frac{d\gamma(\bar z)}{d\bar z}
$$

Comment: Thanks, its clear now. But any comments on the last question? "why does this tell us the invariance of $\Delta$?"